# RSA two factor authentication using C# SOAP serializer

Tags: java, c#, .net, soapui, serialization

We are currently trying to send/receive SOAP messages to the RSA - adaptive authentication API.
Unfortunately we are unable to obtain the logs and therefore have been forced to use black box testing.

We're currently using SOAPUI for testing and have made successful calls/responses however, when we generate the message in our solution we are not getting the same results.
From my understanding, we are receiving an error because SOAPUI is using a java serializer compared to our solution which is developed in .NET using the ISerializer.

Has anyone come across this problem before and has some insight?

Cheers,
James